# Promisify child process communication

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, es6-promise, child-process

Is it possible to promisify the communcation between 2 processes?

Like, send a message, then wait until a response is received, then do something.

I've written the code but I have no idea how to resolve the promises associated with sent messages, because the response messages are received in a different function, out of the promise scope :|

```
var worker, job_id, promises = [];

worker = child_process.fork(__dirname + '/w.js');
worker.on('message', (message) => {
  let job_id = message.job_id;
  // how to resolve promises[job_id] ??
});

function send(data){
  job_id++;
  data.job_id = job_id;
  worker.send(data);

  var promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // how to resolve this in the message handler?
  });

  promises[job_id] = promise;
}
```

This function should be used like

```
send(data).then((response_message) => {
  console.log(response_message);
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't store the promises, store the `resolve` functions:

```
const worker = child_process.fork(__dirname + '/w.js');
const jobs = new Map();
let job_id;

worker.on('message', message => {
  const job_id = message.job_id;
  const resolve = jobs.get(job_id);
  jobs.delete(job_id);
  resolve(message);
});

function send(data){
  data.job_id = job_id++;
  worker.send(data);
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    jobs.set(job_id, resolve);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Using promises with Workers is a very good idea but i have difficulty in understanding your needs. You have a huge advantage of being able to send/receive `job_id` as a property of message object to/from the worker per job. This simplifies the task greatly. Just attach your `job_id` to your `data` object in advance and do as follws;

```
function send(worker, data){ // data already has a job_id property
  worker.send(data);
  return new Promise((v,x) => worker.onmessage(v), worker.onmessageerror(x));
}
var data = {data: "someData", job_id: 1};
send(myWorker, data)
.then(m => doSomethingWith(m.job_id, m.data))
```

Even if you don't have the chance to send and receieve `job_id` to/from the Workers you may keep track of the promises by placing them in an array and firing them by `Promise.all()`. This is very beneficial for segmented jobs those spread over several workers.

```
function send(worker, data){ // data has no job_id property
  worker.send(data);
  return new Promise((v,x) => worker.onmessage(v), worker.onmessageerror(x));
}
var segmentedJobs = [job0, job1, job2],
    jobPromises   = segmentedJobs.map((j,i) => Promise.all([send(j),i]));
Promise.all(jobPromises)
       .then(rs => rs.map(([data,id]) => doSomethingWith(data,id)));
```

Yet most of the time the segmented jobs result with interrelated data to be processed consequently. In that case you may just reduce or scan the promises array without even bothering with a job id whatsoever.